# Minted Highlight code with multiple colors

Tags: color, minted, highlighting, fvextra

I would like to highlight a function in minted by giving it a **multiple** background colors. So I would like the same highlight than the following picture

[image]

I succes to highlight  the green line, but I don't see in the documentation how to have different color. Please find the following minted code

```
\begin{minted}[
    linenos,
    tabsize=4,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    highlightlines={1,2},
    highlightcolor=lime]{java}

for (JobConfig jobConfig : INSTANCE.getJobs()) {
    for (PackageConfig packageConfig : jobConfig.getPackages()) {
        if (!packageName.add(packageConfig.getName())) {

\end{minted}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within a `minted` environment you can escape to LaTeX using the `escapeinside` option to change the highlight color. This requires that you set the color globally using `\xglobal` and that you *don't* use the `highlightcolor` option but instead set the color manually before the `minted` environment.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\colorlet{FancyVerbHighlightColor}{lime}
\begin{minted}[
    escapeinside=||,
    linenos,
    tabsize=4,
    numbersep=5pt,
    frame=lines,
    framesep=2mm,
    highlightlines={1,2,3}]{java}
for (JobConfig jobConfig : INSTANCE.getJobs()) {
    for (PackageConfig packageConfig : jobConfig.getPackages()) {
|\xglobal\colorlet{FancyVerbHighlightColor}{LemonChiffon}|        if (!packageName.add(packageConfig.getName())) {
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, very usefull